# PDF of X - Y given pdf of X + Y

Tags: probability

I'm learning Probability and having trouble with derived distributions. I would like some insight on the following question:

Consider a PDF that is positive only within an interval [a,b] and is symmetric around the mean (a +b)/2. Let X and Y be independent random variables that both have this PDF. Suppose that you have calculated the PDF of X + Y, how can you easily obtain the PDF of X - Y?

Any thoughts on this appreciated.

Comment: Nice exercise. Where is this asked?

Comment: In the book "Introduction to Probability" by Dimitri P. Bertsekas, John N. Tsitsiklis on Pg 247

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By symmetry, Y and b+a-Y are identically distributed hence, by independence of (X,Y), the pairs (X,Y) and (X,b+a-Y) are identically distributed. This implies that X+Y and X+(b+a-Y) are identically distributed hence X-Y is distributed like (X+Y)-(b+a), whose distribution is known.